# SSH - do I have multiple keys for different purposes or one key that represents my system?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

Ubuntu 14.04

I'm not too sure about this, If I look in the contents of ~/.ssh/ I have a few files in there, I'm just about to setup a key for use with BitBucket.

I'm not sure if I'm meant to have multiple keys for different purposes or if I should have one key that is used for lots of things to identify me.

Cheers

Comment: Also be aware that if you ssh through systems a lot the "ssh -A" allows for centralized key keeping.

Comment: You ssh key in `~/.ssh` represents you personally, not your system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyway, the first thing you need is to create a pair of private and public ssh keys. It could be done by executing `ssh-keygen` command in the terminal.

To be short - the public key (`id_rsa.pub`) is used by the third-party servers and services like BitBucket to identify you. So you need to provide them this information. For example, add a public key to BitBucket account settings.

The same private/public keys pair could be used by multiple servers and services to identify you at the same time so usually you don't need to create multiple pairs.

Comment: "the first thing you need is to create a pair of private and public ssh keys"                    I already have `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` in `~/.ssh`, as I've used ssh with my raspberry pi previously, I'm confused as to whether I need to make another one for bitbucket or just the same `id_rsa.pub` for them as well. It sounds (from your post) as though I can just reuse this key, is that correct? thanks

Comment: you can reuse it for sure

Comment: also if you have any further concerns - you should check that your desired software (it is about git, as I understood from you question) uses the same ssh-keys pair. Just specify the public key you have to the BitBucket, then try to make some git clone/push/pull commands and see that the authorization works correctly.

Comment: thanks @Andrey, yeah I've added the key but I'm still getting prompted for passwords when I try and push stuff at the mo, ho hum.

Comment: @user3130747: Is it prompting you for the password for the account, or the passphrase for the key? If the latter, you need to use `ssh-agent` to hold your private key (locally) so you can login without entering a password or passphrase.

Comment: @KeithThompson, it's asking for the password like it would have previously with HTTPS. It's as if nothing has happened. I used the keys that were already in ~/.ssh   ,thanks

Comment: @user3130747 well, it should not prompt a password after public key is specified for the third-party service. Maybe there is some extra information we can't see now?

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin, maybe so, I'm not sure what though. I've just tried `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` which said the authenticity couldn't be established, I said that I trusted it, that hasn't helped. If I run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` It now shows that I'm logged on, but then I still have to enter my password to push. So I'm unsure

Comment: @user3130747 could you try to clone/pull/push some code to some bicbucket repository?

Comment: To be clear, have you gone into your GitHub account settings, selected "SSH Keys", clicked "Add SSH key", and copy-and-pasted your *public* key into the form? It will show you a list of the public key(s) you've already submitted. (It's smart enough to reject a private key if you accidentally upload one.)

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin that's what I'm currently doing, trying to push some code to a repo. I'm not sure if it only works with repos that I've set up since adding ssh, don't think that would be the case though (as people would have to go over all their repos and reinitialise them)

Comment: Maybe it is really what @KeithThompson is talking about. You could have made an error when pasting `id_rsa.pub` content to the textarea on the bitbucket settings page. Please double-check it.

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin: Right, the question was about BitBucket. I'm not entirely sure why I assumed it was about GitHub. The settings for BitBucket are very similar.

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin I'm surprised, I deleted the repo and re cloned it from the bitbucket page and now it works. I didn't think that I would have to do that but hey ho I guess. I just tested it by pushing and it worked. Funnily enough I did paste the key in wrong first time, but I got a warning for that ;)

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for your help - I ended up deleting the repo (locally) and recloning it, which seems to have worked. I would like to think there's a cleverer solution but It escaped me. Cheers!

Comment: @user3130747@KeithThompson BTW, just had the same behavior. My collegue has cloned a github repo with HTTPS instead of SSH so nothing worked until changing url. That's the same as to reclone a repo with SSH as you've done recently

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin cheers - so I guess there wasn't an easier solution than recloning using the ssh link?

Answer (score 5):

I use one key per workstation. On each workstation, I generate a new public/private key pair, and then add that to the authorized keys file (or GitHub/Bitbucket account) of all of the machines I need to interact with via SSH.

That way, if my machine is lost, stolen, or I need to replace the hard drive, I can just de-authorize that one machine by deleting its public key from all of the services, while not needing to rotate my keys on all machines.

I have never found a good reason to create a separate key pair per service on a given workstation; that just increases the management overhead without much tangible benefit. You might do it if you were very privacy minded, and didn't want separate services to correlate your keys, but if you're that privacy minded you should already be accessing everything through Tor and probably have entirely separate accounts for each to avoid leaking any information at all.

Comment: thanks @Brian , sounds about right. I managed to confuse myself pretty well though, I wasn't sure if I had to make a new one for each service or reuse the same one